# Problems with creating multi module maven project from SCM

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, subversive

I wish to create a multimodule maven project from SCM, my svn repository is DEVEO. 
Here are the steps i perform in eclipse mars (I have installed m2e plugin + subversive + and required connectors)

1. Right Click Project Explorer > New > Project
2. Maven > Checkout Maven Project from SCM
3. SCM URL :
4. Click Next
5. Click Finish
6. Then there is a popup window saying "No projects found, do you want to create project using new project wizard" I click "OK"
7. From New Project Wizard, I select Maven > Maven Project

And i create my new project.

When i go into my workspace what i see is[image]

A. Project Folder is not created inside maven folder
B. The Maven folder has no trunk, branches or tags

Ideally project should be created inside Maven folder > trunk. Any Helps

Comment: Does your URL point at the `trunk` of your SVN repo?

Comment: No it doesnt ! But if i remeber correctly that is not mandatory and svn does that for you from eclipse.

Comment: I recommend that you follow @VonC's advice below anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All,

My purpose was to just use eclipse subversive plugin and not install any external svn client like tortoise. Its kind of a workaround but eventually you can do everything from eclipse. So here is what i did

a. I completely ignored the m2e way of creating project from scm as mentioned in my question.

I simply created a maven multi-module project structure. Right click the root project > Team > Share Project

and then while i am adding the project i use the option "use multiple projects layout with specified root name" and rest is very clear.

I even did not had to create a trunk or tag or branch in my repo separately. It was all done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you:

- checkout manually your svn repo *outside* the Eclipse workspace (without Eclipse running)
- make sure your multi-module projet is working (mvn clean install)

Then you can *import* that project into Eclipse ([File/Import Maven project](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html)), and Eclipse should detect everything (maven + SVN)